# Transfer int values from one class to another

Tags: java, class, integer

Main Class:
http://gyazo.com/0a77cdba8a876eb2f8e0b8576d9c336c

Class calling the int:
http://gyazo.com/bb8d8532a9a93491f97122cba4a8c331

It claims the int does not exist...

Comment: How about tagging the question a little better than [tag:integer], like adding [tag:java]? It helps you get answers :) Actually [tag:integer] us nonsense because it has nothing to do with integers, the same can apply to a string or such.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring it in a local context, so it is only visible within the main method. Try setting it as a class property.

Comment: Not really a good class design to make a "class property" (i.e. a Class static variable that one calls from another class.  Would still recommend using a method call or some other mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable a was declared in the Main method (so it is local to that method). You might get that variable value to the "called class" several different ways (not sure which may apply, provide full code):

- Declare variable in "main" class; provide method in "main" class to call and get the variable
- Find a way to pass the variable to the UI classes and then call your method with that variable value.